# Converting CRSP Daily Stock Returns into Zoo Object in R

Tags: r, finance, zoo, accounting

**Note: I've found a solution myself and will put it in an answer below this post. Preserving this for others since it took me a while to figure out and it seems like common task in accounting and finance research.**

Suppose I currently have a data frame that contains daily stock returns for a bunch of different firms by date, and the data is structured such that one column contains the firm identifier (ticker), a second column contains the date, and a third column contains the return. (This is the format that one gets from [CRSP](http://www.crsp.com/).) How do I convert these data into a `zoo` object in `R`?

Reproducible code to get the data frame that needs to be converted to a `zoo` object:

```
Z.date <- c(as.Date(12501:12505), as.Date(12501:12506), as.Date(12501:12505))
Z.firm <- c(rep("A", 5), rep("B", 6), rep("C", 5))
set.seed(50)
Z.returns <- c(rnorm(5), rnorm(6), rnorm(5))
df <- data.frame(Z.date, Z.firm, Z.returns)
```

Which yields:

```
       Z.date Z.firm   Z.returns
1  2004-03-24      A  0.54966989
2  2004-03-25      A -0.84160374
3  2004-03-26      A  0.03299794
4  2004-03-27      A  0.52414971
5  2004-03-28      A -1.72760411
6  2004-03-24      B -0.27786453
7  2004-03-25      B  0.36082844
8  2004-03-26      B -0.59091244
9  2004-03-27      B  0.97559055
10 2004-03-28      B -1.44574995
11 2004-03-29      B  0.29520677
12 2004-03-24      C  0.55475223
13 2004-03-25      C -0.49863554
14 2004-03-26      C  0.19573384
15 2004-03-27      C -0.45554055
16 2004-03-28      C -0.36285547
```

The desired `zoo` object should look something like this:

```
              A            B            C
2004-03-24     0.54966989  -0.27786453   0.55475223
2004-03-25    -0.84160374   0.36082844  -0.49863554
2004-03-26     0.03299794  -0.59091244   0.19573384
2004-03-27     0.52414971   0.97559055  -0.45554055
2004-03-28    -1.72760411  -1.44574995  -0.36285547
2004-03-29     NA           0.29520677   NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read.zoo` with the `split` argument:

```
read.zoo(df, split = "Z.firm")
```

giving this `"zoo"` object:

```
                     A          B          C
2004-03-24  0.54966989 -0.2778645  0.5547522
2004-03-25 -0.84160374  0.3608284 -0.4986355
2004-03-26  0.03299794 -0.5909124  0.1957338
2004-03-27  0.52414971  0.9755906 -0.4555405
2004-03-28 -1.72760411 -1.4457499 -0.3628555
2004-03-29          NA  0.2952068         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution. Flip the data frame using the `tidyr` package and then convert it to a `zoo` object.

```
library(zoo)
library(tidyr)

wide_df <- tidyr::spread(df, key = Z.firm, value = Z.returns) # flip using tidyr's spread()
df.zoo <- zoo(wide_df, order.by = wide_df$Z.date) # convert to zoo, ordering by date
df.zoo <- df.zoo[, colnames(df.zoo) != "Z.date"] # get rid of the superfluous date column
```

This yields:

```
           A           B          C         
2004-03-24  0.54966989 -0.2778645  0.5547522
2004-03-25 -0.84160374  0.3608284 -0.4986355
2004-03-26  0.03299794 -0.5909124  0.1957338
2004-03-27  0.52414971  0.9755906 -0.4555405
2004-03-28 -1.72760411 -1.4457499 -0.3628555
2004-03-29 <NA>         0.2952068 <NA>
```